# attach decorative terracotta disk to outside of house

Tags: exterior

I have a couple of exterior terracotta disks that I’d like to attach to the outside of my house. How can I go about doing so? They have no real fixing holes on the back as you can see in the picture.

[image: Picture of back of disk]

Comment: What is the exterior of the house made of, and how big/heavy are these disks?

Comment: Wife went to a flea market did she?

Answer (score 1):

Typically those would be installed in/with mortar or stucco, which would key into the depression in the back.

That or construction adhesive would be the logical approach unless you want them removable and don't mind something like 3 stainless steel nails capturing it around the edge (mark, remove, drive two, place disk, drive the third with care) or 3 L hooks.